I can't find Device Logs with all logs in Xcode
I get crash log from ios app review rejection.
I change extension name from .txt to .crash.
And I goes to Window > Devices and Simulators,
But I can't find Devices Logs but I have Open Recent Logs

After If I open previous crash file, then I make me select Runner file.

Then If I click the recent one, it crashes.
I think It is not crash file coming from my device, but from ios review..?
How can I symbolicate crash log that I get from iOS team?
